# How do I resize an image of a map so that it isn't distorted?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So currently I'm importing this Mercator project and its saved in my computer as a 593 x 479 png image and looks like so:

[image]

I'm importing the image like so:

```
$plt.figure(figsize=(25,25), dpi=100)
font = {'family' : 'Arial',
        'size'   : 22}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
plt.xlim(-180, 180)
plt.ylim(-90,90)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.xticks(np.arange(-180, 181, 30))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-90, 91, 30))
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'box')
os.chdir('/Users/Jbats814/Desktop/School/Research/Radical_Ein_Data/')
img = imread("Mercator.png")
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])
plt.grid()
plt.show()$
```

However, when I get my output, the image is distorted as it has been stretched out like so:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it's because you are mapping a square image onto a shape that is rectangular: `extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90]`

Comment: Because y-axis (latitude) lines are not equidistant to the x-axis (longitude) lines in a Mercator Projection, i.e. square Verify with some of the lat/log points.

Comment: If thats the case and I need to make my longitude and latitude lines equidistant, how do I do that?

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m103/mercator/mercator.html here is a good explanation of the math behind Mercator Projections.